# jQuery mobile List with form - did I get the markup wrong? Wrapping issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble with a list with form. See [example here](http://jsbin.com/mewarixepe/5/edit)

Problem is that the labels does not wrap, they expand into the controls

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <form action="form.php" method="post">
     <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="a">This is aa long text that does not wrap before it hits the control</label>
            <select name="a" id="a" data-mini="true">
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="a">a</option>
            </select>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

I guess I got the markup wrong, but I can't spot the problem

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, just remove the list (`<ul>`) and replace `<li>` with `<div>` tags.

See [updated example](http://jsbin.com/nemuxiseru/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Any idea how to get the "listview" look - like in Form example on this page https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/

Comment: if you stretch the labels in that example they do not wrap, so you're back to the start. I think you need to modify the label CSS to make it work as you like